# How to define a second environment variable when the first one wasn't resolved in Spring?

Tags: spring

Suppose I have configuration property called `app.database.url`. I need to search for the URL in two places, so I created resolvable property like that:

```
app.database.url=${APP_DATABASE_URL:DEFAULT_URL}
```

However instead of searching for the second environment variable with key `DEFAULT_URL`, spring resolves this property as a string with value `DEFAULT_URL`. Is is possible to tell spring that the second argument is also should be resolved by environment variables?

Comment: When using with `@Value` annotation, `@Value("#{'${APP_DATABASE_URL:${DEFAULT_URL:}}'}")` can be used, so could you please try same idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just use this:

```
app.database.url=${APP_DATABASE_URL:${DEFAULT_URL}}
```